# StatefulPersistenceContext: NullPointerException in hibernate library

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, jpa

I have an application running in Tomcat 7.0.37 for 2 years without any error but yesterday it gave this one:

```
Exception in thread "datamanager-general-info" java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.hibernate.engine.StatefulPersistenceContext.clear(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:217)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.cleanup(SessionImpl.java:623)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.close(SessionImpl.java:351)
at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl.close(EntityManagerImpl.java:151)
at com.xxxxxxxxxx.DataManager$GeneralInfo.buildPages(DataManager.java:358)
```

The error starts in class DataManager in this line, when closing the EntityManager:

```
EntityManager em  = null;
try {
    em = JPAUtil.getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();

    // code here...

} catch (Exception e) {
    // nothing
} finally {
    if (em != null && em.isOpen()) {
        em.close(); <-- line 358
    }
}
```

Now, its repeating every 2-3 hours.

I'm using hibernate 3.6.10 with JPA 2.0 api 1.0.1 and C3P0.

Any help is well welcome!

Comment: Assuming your Hibernate and Tomcat versions have not changed, I would first look at your database (which connects to Hibernate) to see if maybe something happened there.

Comment: The database is managed by other team. They informed that no changes were made.

Comment: WIthout knowing more about your code and where/when this exception is happening, I'm afraid we won't be able to help you much.

Comment: I have updated the question adding the line in the code that begins the error

Comment: Can you debug the above code?  There is some dirty state which cannot be persisted.

Comment: It is not possible. Is in production enviroment. The unique change made in this days was 2 days ago they shutdown the VM and Tomcat didn't stop correctly. Its possible hibernate had something cached or stored in tomcats work directory?

Comment: This exception occurred to me after changing Hibernate properties.

Comment: I remenber that, in that case the problem was something with multithread system. Some objects (obtained with one entity manager) traveled to another thread with other entity manager and hibernate became crazy.